# Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am getting this error **A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path**

I have used setState in componentWillReceiveProps :

```
this.setState({ checkboxes: nextProps.data.my_details});
```

In render function i have generated dynamic checkboxes and based on the value i am getting i am showing checkbox checked or not. see code below :

```
renderSubCategory(data, indexParent){
  let indexParent1 = indexParent;
  const {checkboxes} = this.state;
  return checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories.map((data1, index1) => {
    return(
        <View key={index1}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <CheckBox
                        label={data1.name}
                        labelStyle={{fontSize:14}}
                        size={25}
                        color='#17bb8f'
                        checked={data1.status_code === 0 ? false : true}
                        onPress={(checked)=>this.handlePressCheckedBox(index1, checked, indexParent1)}
                    />
            </View>
       </View>
     )
   })
}
```

Now onPress function of checkbox i am changing the state of checkbox and getting mutation error.

```
handlePressCheckedBox = (index,checked, indexParent1) => {
    const {checkboxes} = this.state;
    if(checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code === 0){
      checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 1;
    }else{
      checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 0;
    }
    this.setState({
        checkboxes
    });
 }
```

Please Help me Resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from this part of code:

```
const {checkboxes} = this.state;
if(checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code === 0){
   checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 1;
}else{
   checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 0;
}
```

Doing something like this:

```
const {checkboxes} = this.state;
```

is similar to:

```
const checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;
```

After that, when you change the status_code, you change manually the state instead of using the setState (the reference is changed).

**Solution:**
Use a spread iterator to pass a copy of your state instead of your state reference

```
const checkboxes = {...this.state.checkboxes};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @jpclair  I know the problem is because of those line where i ma changing status. I also tried solution you have given but still getting mutation error. Can you help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkboxes` state is being mutated by the `handlePressCheckedBox`function.

Specifically, these lines are the culprits:
`checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 1;`
`checkboxes[indexParent1].sub_categories[index].status_code = 0;`

Comment: Thank for reply @Derek. I know that. Do you have any solution ?